# Vue 3 and webpack 5 - Error: "module property was removed from Dependency"

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, webpack-5

Using webpack 5 to build vue projects throws the error:
"Error: module property was removed from Dependency"

My understanding is webpack have removed a monkey-patch that vue is relying on.:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8537

What options are there for resolving this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For now a workaround will be just to downgrade to version 4 (`package.json`)

```
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
```

Comment: Good point, this is currently what I am doing.

Comment: What if you need a webpack5-specific plugin, such as Module Federation..?

Comment: @Fadils as I mentioned this this just a workaround, I didn't find a proper solution yet

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they are working on adding webpack 5 support to vue3. I'll update this answer once it is released.

See:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/pull/5611